# Django - display list of all users from auth.models in ListView Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-class-based-views

Hi i am working on a Hotel website and am trying to display list of all the users from the admin site onto my dashboard in a listview

```
class UsersListView(ListView):
template_name = 'dashboard/users/userlist.html'
login_url = '/login/'
redirect_field_name = 'user_list'


def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.filter(
        username=self.request.user
    )
```

The above code only displayed the logged in user not all the list. Is there a way to display the active and inactive state of the users?

```
<thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>SN</th>
                  <th>Users</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for user in object_list %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.username }}</td>
                  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.is_active}}</td>
```

Comment: `User.objects.all()` but in case you have a lot of users you need to think about pagination.

Comment: I have paginated the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are filtering the `User QuerySet` to only show you the user that is doing the request to the server.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
```

Getting all users is as simple as using the `.all()` function:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.all()
```

You should check the [Django QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/) to understand how to work with `QuerySet` objects.